# split into train and test by group+ sklearn cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe in python as shown below:

```
data    labels    group
 aa       1         x
 bb       1         x
 cc       2         y
 dd       1         y
 ee       3         y
 ff       3         x
 gg       3         z
 hh       1         z
 ii       2         z
```

It is straight forward to randomly split into 70:30 for training and test sets. Here, i need to split into test and train so that 70% of data within each `group` should be in training and 30% of data within each group as test data. Then predict and find accuracy of test data within each group.

I find that `cross_val_score` does the splitting, fitting model and predciting with the below function:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
>>> scores = cross_val_score(model, data, labels, cv=5)
>>> scores
```

The documentation of `cross_val_score` have `groups` parameter which says:

```
groups : array-like, with shape (n_samples,), optional
Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into 
train/test set.
```

Here, i need to split into test and train so that 70% of data within each group should be in training and 30% of data within each group as test data. Then predict and find accuracy of test data within each group. Does using the groups parameter in the below way split data within each group into training and test data and make the predictions?

```
>>> scores = cross_val_score(model, data, labels, groups= group, cv=5)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use pandas to filter based on group, and then use the filtered data to split right?

Comment: Are you looking for the `stratify` parameter in the train_test_split?

Comment: Lets's say we split the data randomly into 70:30. But Splitting should consider that 70% of data from each group goes to training and 30% data from each group should go to test data set instead of making the training set (70%) that has values from only few groups. Does stratify does the same?

Comment: Be careful with terminology here. In sklearn "groups" has a very different meaning than OP is using. In sklearn, "groups" (e.g as argument to `cross_val_score`, or in  `GroupKFold`) are to be segregated across splits or folds, not balanced across them.

Answer (score 2):

The `stratify` parameter of `train_test_split` takes the labels on which to stratify the selection to maintain proper class balance.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['data'], df['labels'],stratify=df['group'])
```

On your toy dataset, it seems to be what you want, but I would try it on your full dataset and verify whether the classes are balanced by checking counts of data in your train and test sets

Comment: `cross_val_score` also contains the `groups` parameter which, from the docs, you pass "Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into train/test set." so that should also work the same way

Comment: As I commented to the original question, the `groups` parameter does the complete opposite of the what is asked, it puts the groups into either train or test.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I know straight from the function, but you could `apply` `train_test_split` to the groups and then concatenate the splits with `pd.concat` like:

```
def train_test_split_group(x):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x['data'],x['labels'])
    return pd.Series([X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test], index=['X_train', 'X_test', 'y_train', 'y_test'])

final = df.groupby('group').apply(train_test_split_group).apply(lambda x: pd.concat(x.tolist()))
final['X_train'].dropna()

1    bb
3    dd
4    ee
5    ff
6    gg
7    hh
Name: X_train, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify your train and validation sets in this way you will need to create a cross-validation object and not use the `cv=5` argument to `cross_val_score`. The trick is you want to stratify the folds but not based on the classes in `y`, rather based on another column of data. I think you can use `StratifiedShuffleSplit` for this like the following.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], 
              [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

groups_to_stratify = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits()

print(sss)       

# Note groups_to_stratify is used in the split() function not y as usual
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, groups_to_stratify):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print("TRAIN indices:", train_index, 
          "train groups", groups_to_stratify[train_index],
          "TEST indices:", test_index, 
          "test groups", groups_to_stratify[test_index])
```

Comment: Just to let everyone know, this solution does not work if you want to integrate a target (y) dependent pipeline transformations to be cross-validated.